# Shapes size in layered-array is not same

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list

I want to draw two circle with the same size in a `layer-list`. and here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/clickable"
                android:width="@dimen/clickable" />

            <solid android:color="#ff000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="32dp" android:left="32dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/clickable"
                android:width="@dimen/clickable" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but the result drawable is like this:

[image]

I expected two circle in same size. what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

one of attribute is

```
 <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp">
```

and secound one is this so may be i think prob is this

```
<item android:top="32dp" android:left="32dp">
```